# Two intervals of collecting data in Collectd on the same Postgres database

Tags: database, postgresql, intervals, collectd

I would like to ask if there is a possibility to set up two different intervals of collecting data in the Collectd tool. The issue is that I want to collect data (perform two different select queries) from one Postgres database with different intervals but the Collectd supports only one interval.

I cannot use DBI plugin because there I have different interval.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily achieved by using the block form of `LoadPlugin`:

```
Interval 10
LoadPlugin cpu
LoadPlugin memory
<LoadPlugin df>
  Interval 60
</LoadPlugin>
```

In this example, `cpu` and `memory` plugins inherit the global `10` second interval, whereas `df` will only run every 60 seconds.

If you want different intervals for the same plugin, it really depends. Either the plugin supports it (see its man page), or you have to run multiple instances of collectd.

Checking the source code of the `dbi` plugin, there's an [undocumented config option](https://github.com/collectd/collectd/blob/master/src/dbi.c#L218) in the `Database` block, which should allow you to set the interval at the db level. If this works, but you still need it at query granularity, you can work around this limitation by creating multiple `Database` blocks for the same underlying db:

```
<Database "plugin_instance1">
  Driver "mysql"
  Interval 120
  ...
</Database>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Anyway I have two queries on same database and I need different interval for each query. Maybe two instances of collectd would help, but I want to keep only one instance of this tool.

Comment: I just updated my answer with a possible solution using only one instance of collectd

Comment: Thank you. I knew of this option but the postgres driver wasnt working in DBI plugin (dont know why)